# I keep getting "too many positional arguments to make function call "

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a Tic tac toe game an im trying to call a function but it wont let me call it

```
def full_board_check(board):
    for i in range(1,10):
        if space_check(board,i):
            return False
```

space_check should check the free spaces on the board but it wont work

Comment: Hi Anthony, which part is not working? Can you provide an example of "board"  and explain when it does not work?

Comment: Can we see what the space_check function looks like too? That's where the problem lies.

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell you the fix until I have a look at the code but can explain the error.

It means that you're giving too many positional arguments than it is expecting. Okay.

So what's positional arguments? Positional arguments are the ones in which the order/position in call matters e.g. `divide(x, y) => x/y`. It matters which order/position `x, y` go in. If you do `divide(2, 3) != divide(3, 2)`.

Python also has labeled arguments e.g. `divide(numerator=0, denominator=1) => numerator/denominator` now if you call it like this `divide(denominator=3, numerator=2) => 2/3` it still looks for 2/3 rather than switching them around.

So it's likely your `space_check` function only accepts single positional and rest are named. So you need to look at the docs and find that out and use it.

[Read more here.](https://treyhunner.com/2018/04/keyword-arguments-in-python/)